# Filestream.write does not work

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I used the following code to write on `*.txt` file, but nothing happens. Even, there is no exception.

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\file.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None);    //Creating a stream with certain features to a file

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);    //Use the fs to write

      //  writer.WriteLine(Text.Text);  none of the following methods works
        writer.Write("aaaaaaaaaaaa");

        fs.Close();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to enclose it in a using block like this:

```
using ( FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\file.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None))
using (StreamWriter fw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    fw.Write("aaaaaaaaaaaa");
}
```

A `StreamWriter` buffers data before writing it to the underlying stream. You need to flushes the buffer by disposing the `StreamWriter`

Comment: Or use `File.CreateText` or even just `File.WriteAllText`, both of which are significantly simpler...